# How do I capture video of a changing CIImage without using the camera?

Tags: ios, swift, avassetwriter, ciimage

I've already asked a question without any responses here:
[How do I record changes on a CIImage to a video using AVAssetWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58735258/how-do-i-record-changes-on-a-ciimage-to-a-video-using-avassetwriter)

But perhaps my question needs to be simpler. My Google search has been fruitless. **How do I capture video of a changing CIImage in real time, without using the camera?**

Using captureOutput, I get a CMSampleBuffer, which I can make into a CVPixelBuffer. AVAssetWriterInput's mediaType is set to video, but I think it expects compressed video. In addition, I'm not clear if the AVAssetWriterInput expectsMediaDataInRealTime property should be set to true or not.

Seems like it should be fairly simple, but everything I attempted makes my AVAssetWriter's status fail.

Here is my last attempt at making this work. Still failing:

```
@objc func importLivePreview(){

    guard var importedImage = importedDryCIImage else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(){

        // apply filter to camera image
        // this is what makes the CIImage appear that it is changing
        importedImage = self.applyFilterAndReturnImage(ciImage: importedImage, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.right, currentCameraRes:currentCameraRes!)


        if self.videoIsRecording &&
           self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {

            guard let writer: AVAssetWriter = self.assetWriter, writer.status == .writing else {
                return
            }                       

            guard let cv:CVPixelBuffer = self.buffer(from: importedImage) else {
                print("CVPixelBuffer could not be created.")
                return
            }

            self.MTLContext?.render(_:importedImage, to:cv)

            self.currentSampleTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, preferredTimescale: 1000000000)

            guard let currentSampleTime = self.currentSampleTime else {
                return
            }

            let success = self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.append(cv, withPresentationTime: currentSampleTime)

            if success == false {
                print("Pixel Buffer input failed")
            }

        }

        guard let MTLView = self.MTLCaptureView else {
            print("MTLCaptureView is not found or nil.")
            return
        }

        // update the MTKView with the changed CIImage so the user can see the changed image
        MTLView.image = importedImage


    }           

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. The problem was is that I wasn't offsetting currentSampleTime. This example doesn't have accurate offsets, but it shows that it needs to be added onto the last time.

```
@objc func importLivePreview(){

    guard var importedImage = importedDryCIImage else { return }

    DispatchQueue.main.async(){

        // apply filter to camera image
        // this is what makes the CIImage appear that it is changing
        importedImage = self.applyFilterAndReturnImage(ciImage: importedImage, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.right, currentCameraRes:currentCameraRes!)


        if self.videoIsRecording &&
           self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.assetWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData == true {

            guard let writer: AVAssetWriter = self.assetWriter, writer.status == .writing else {
                return
            }                       

            guard let cv:CVPixelBuffer = self.buffer(from: importedImage) else {
                print("CVPixelBuffer could not be created.")
                return
            }

            self.MTLContext?.render(_:importedImage, to:cv)

            guard let currentSampleTime = self.currentSampleTime else {
                return
            }

            // offset currentSampleTime
            let sampleTimeOffset = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, preferredTimescale: 1000000000)

            self.currentSampleTime = CMTimeAdd(currentSampleTime, sampleTimeOffset)

            print("currentSampleTime = \(String(describing: currentSampleTime))")

            let success = self.assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.append(cv, withPresentationTime: currentSampleTime)

            if success == false {
                print("Pixel Buffer input failed")
            }

        }

        guard let MTLView = self.MTLCaptureView else {
            print("MTLCaptureView is not found or nil.")
            return
        }

        // update the MTKView with the changed CIImage so the user can see the changed image
        MTLView.image = importedImage


    }           

}
```